# Converting JSON schema to angularjs Form fields

Tags: angularjs, frontend, jsonschema, angular-fullstack

i am new to angularjs trying to design a application which will convert a json schema to form fields. I tried using directives but no hope.
What i trying to do is to make the attributes of the input tag dynamic, dont know where to start.

Example:

```
<input type="text" ng-maxllength=100 required/>
<input type="text"/>
```

for these two above tags i want to create a common directive that could handle both.

I tried

```py
[{"text":{"name":"Name","model_name":"name","required":true}},
            {"text":{"name":"Email","model_name":"email","required":true}},
            {"text":{"name":"password","model_name":"pass","required":false}},]
```

this is the json i am using
in directive i tried build a string using the json
Directive

```js
.directive('tpttext',[function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            fields: '=fields'
        },
        template: function(e,a){
            var out='<input id={{fields.name}}  class={{fields.name}} type="text" ng-model="formData.{{fields.model_nname}}" name={{fields.name}}'
            if(fields.required==true){
            out=out+'required/>'
            out=out+'<validator status="formname.{{fields.name}}"><message key="required">This field is required</message></validator>'
            }else{
                out=out+'/>'
            }
          
            return out;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: _"I tried using directives..."_ please show us what you have tried. We cannot read your mind and no what is wrong. I have already done something similar in the past so I know it can be done, I just don't know what you've tried.

Comment: @VikramChandranB Like this? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73495647/angular-dynamic-reactive-form-error-cannot-set-properties-of-undefined-settin)

Comment: Yea but in angularjs